# Can anybody help me how to check is there in table users user with this username?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Can anybody help me how to check is there in table users user with this username ?
I am using SQLite3, PHP and PDO and I wrote code like

```
 try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/db/db_users.db');
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username= :username';// moze LIMIT 1 da se stavi jer je sigurno jedan sa istim username i password sine
    $sth = $db->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return (array('message' => 'error'));
}
```

but there is no single_fetch or I cannot find. Can anybody help me how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you try with $sth->fetchOne() or $sth->fetchRow()

Comment: Or try with: $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username= :username LIMIT 1';

Comment: @Faraona: there is not `fetchOne` or `fetchRow`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single fetch.. since there is only one row you jsut fetch it like normal and dont loop then close the cursor. If youre only after a specific value you can jut pull the column too...

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/db/db_users.db');

    // add an alias.. not really necessary but good practice
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS usercount FROM users WHERE username= :username';

    $sth = $db->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute(array(':username' => $username));

    // just call regular fetch for the first an only result
    // use fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) or fetchColumn to jsut get 
    // a single column value from the row
    $result = $sth->fetchColumn(0);

    // be nice and close the cursor since we are done.
    $sth->closeCursor();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    return (array('message' => 'error'));
}
```